# How do I enable Linux to make use of desktop.ini files?

Tags: linux, files-folders, xdg, desktop.ini

I've noticed that sometimes when transferring media from Windows to Linux, `desktop.ini` created by Windows are included. These files include useful metadata, such as the icon for the folder and more.

Typically, Linux systems use the XDG desktop file standard (`.desktop`). These files seem capable of roughly everything that `desktop.ini` files are capable of.

My first instinct was to create a simple script to convert these files. This is possible (I've converted many of these files by hand), but is not ideal, as either file might go out of sync.

I've seen that Steam seems to interact with these in some interesting ways, but often doesn't properly read program arguments from `.desktop` files. It's also a huge hassle to work with in general.

Is there a setting in KDE or Gnome to enable (partial) support for `desktop.ini` files? I couldn't find any settings for this on my system - but I know there's tons of settings that haven't yet been exposed graphically. Is there an extension, or would such an extension even be possible?

If extensive support for `desktop.ini` requires Wine -that's fine by me. I don't think folder icons would require that, however.

In theory, this is as simple as just supporting the icon attribute in the desktop.ini file. Further support is nice as well, but 100% support all in one day? Not what I'm asking.

Comment: I suppose that you could rewrite the XORG server to read and write desktop.ini files, but that would be a lot of work. While .desktop files are similar, they are not the same, and the information stored in each will differ. The fundamental architectures and philosophies of these OSes differ, and so work to allow closer coexistence tends to be very complex and involved.

Comment: The file manager? I guess I assumed that, as the desktop.ini folders are used to control how a folder's contents are rendered, that would be a function of the window manager, but I suppose a file manager would also read that data. So, you'd have to rewrite Dolphin instead of whatever window manager you're using, though that may also be 6 of one, half-dozen of another. Probably both need to support it. But, I don't know that it is a strawman: I wasn't saying it was impossible, just that you're assuming because they perform SIMILAR tasks, they must be more similar than they MAY be.

Comment: Ah, you're assuming I know that and was using it as a taunt or something. Apologies for giving that appearance. The truth is more pedestrian: I'm taking what I know about Windows and applying it with due ignorance to a system I am familiar with, but not AS familiar with.

Comment: My bad there. Just had a much less helpful "answer" in reply to my post that was very much doing that sort of thing. I guess I was more hostile than I should have been. Sorry about that. (I've now deleted those comments of mine. No need for them anymore)

Comment: What you are trying to do is much more complex than just setting up the Linux counterpart.  I posted the same thing earlier

Comment: You can't use these files automatically in Linux. You may do so manually, using whatever parts of the files that you can/wish to use.

Comment: The answer gave more or less the same info, and it was good info. It is probably possible to do what you're asking, but you still seem to think it is a relatively simple thing, or there is already a product or tool that does it. You've already done the work yourself, per your comments on that answer, and so could probably put together a shell script that would do what you want without requiring rewrites of the applications.

Comment: See the edit. I don't want 100% support on day one. That's not possible. I'm mostly just asking for support for the image property. Other things are also doable.

Comment: @music2myear as mentioned in the question, that's not a long-term solution. The files would become out of sync.

Comment: @John if your answer was "It's not an available setting in any Linux DE right now and there is no tool to facilitate this right now," then I would have accepted it. Your answer was just detailing the possible problems with adding 100% support. Thus, not an answer.

Comment: Lastly, since many seem to think I want 100% support - I've tried to indicate that isn't needed and isn't what I want. I don't know how to further clarify this.

Comment: "It's not an available setting in any Linux DE right now and there is no tool to facilitate this right now,"     ......  I did say (in somewhat different words) that you could not do this. Yet you downvoted me and I assure you I do not downvote you.  You just wasted my time.

Comment: @John I didn't downvote you. I replied that the quality was dubious, checked back an hour later, and noticed it was gone.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it is not an available setting in any Linux DE right now, and there is currently no tool to facilitate this.

While some attributes like the desktop icon attribute are 1:1, not all attributes are.

Specific things that file explorers on Linux would likely *not* support are

- Launcher support (most arguments would be assuming a DOS-like or Windows environment, and would thus require Wine to function properly. If Wine *is* installed, it's still theoretically doable)
- Settings unique to Windows in particular (no Linux app is beholden to these settings, but may choose to check them of course)

Good luck, and I hope such support gets added someday.